# \b not working as expected with sed command

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to solve one task given to me by using `sed` only. The task is:

> Given  lines of credit card numbers, mask the first  digits of each credit card number with an asterisk (i.e., *) and print the masked card number on a new line. Each credit card number consists of four space-separated groups of four digits. For example, the credit card number 1234 5678 9101 1234 would be masked and printed as **** **** **** 1234.

I have successfully used the following command. It is working as expected and printing the desired output.

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\s\)\{3\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)/**** **** **** \2/'
```

However, I was trying another solution with `\b` and it is not working. I am not able to understand why it is not working. `\b` should match the beginning and the space between the words. I know it can be solved with `\s` but I want to understand what's wrong with the solution with `\b` only.

```
sed 's/\(\b[0-9]\{4\}\b\)\{3\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)/**** **** **** \2/'
```

**NOTE: Since I have a working solution for it. I just want to understand why my solution using `\b` is not working.**

Comment: What version of sed are you using? Different versions recognize different regular expressions.

Comment: You might consider: `sed -E 's/[[:digit:]]{4}([^[:digit:]])/****\1/g'`

Comment: `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`. I just want to understand why \b version doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure why my question has been downvoted!

Comment: For some reason my answer was also downvoted. I have upvoted question to neutralize an unnecessary downvote.

Comment: After reading the documents, i think my question isn't duplicate because the problem with my expression was I couldn't understand how repetition works in regular expression and how word boundary behaves. So, the issue is how an expression behave when repetition and word boundary are used together. Thanks anyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` does work in `gnu sed` but your 2nd regex is incorrect.

You should be using:

```
sed 's/\b\([0-9]\{4\}\s\)\{3\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)/**** **** **** \2/' file
```

or with `-E`

```
sed -E 's/\b([0-9]{4}\s){3}([0-9]{4})/**** **** **** \2/' file
```

Note that second `\b` should be replaced with `\s` (whitespace) since your inout text has spaces between numbers.

[Here is a good article on **Word Boundaries**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: What's wrong with it? I know I can do it with `\s` as I have already solved the problem but not sure why `\b` doesn't work inside regex sub-expression?

Comment: `\b` does work as you can see in my regex as well. But `\b` is a word boundary and it cannot match a space. You input has `1234 5678 9101 1234` so you need to match space between numbers as well.

Comment: So even `sed 's/\(\b[0-9]\{4\}\b\s\)\{3\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)/**** **** **** \2/'` will work for you but it will be a bit inefficient because of redundant `\b`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is `\b` only matches the position not the character. Your last comment helped me understand that. Thanks

Comment: [Here is good read on word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Thanks. It can clear all of my questions. You can add that link to your answers as well.